# How to check if user selected file(s) my Sandboxed app has permission to write?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

I'm enabling sandboxing in my OS X app to resubmit to the app store and I'm trying to find the most elegant way to make sure the user can only select resources my app has permissions to change.

Stripped down scenario:

1. user selects a picture on the file system via an `NSOpenPanel`
2. user clicks the `Process Picture` button on the app
3. app retrieves information from the internet
4. app alters the picture's metadata.

After the user is done selecting the pictures, I want to make sure each one is located under the Pictures folder otherwise my write to the physical file will simply silently fail.

Apple [recommends the following to determine the Pictures folder's location:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html)

> The Pictures directory contains the user’s images and photos. To get
>   the path to this directory use the NSPicturesDirectory search path key
>   with the NSUserDomainMask domain.

Implementing the above gives me a path that looks like this:
`/Users/thomas/Library/Containers/com.blazingfrog.latipics/Data/Pictures/picture1.jpg`

But when I want to see what pictures the user selected,`[myOpenPanel URLs]` returns `/Users/thomas/Pictures/picture1.jpg`

**These two paths are logically identical but look very different. How can I compare them in way that works every time?**

In case it helps, to prepare my app for sandboxing I did the following

- enabled Entitlements in XCode
- enabled App Sandboxing
- enabled File System (Read)
- enabled allowing Incoming/Outgoing Network Connections
- enabled Pictures Folder access (Read/Write)

Comment: "otherwise my write to the physical file will simply silently fail" can you explain that? What happens when you try to just open up the file (for writing)? Does that fail? What about if you use one of the libc functions like `fopen`?

Comment: I use a third-party utility that creates a temp file (non-destructive editing) that is ultimately deleted when the picture has been successfully processed. So to answer your question, my app does not directly open up the file.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should almost **never** fail silently. If something goes wrong, report it to the user, as best you can. This is exactly what `NSError` is designed for.
2. You should almost **never** attempt to figure out if an operation will succeed before trying it. Doing so leaves you open to race conditions. Instead go ahead and try the operation; if it fails, handle that gracefully.
3. It sounds like you actually want the `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` entitlement. This will give you write access to any files the user selects using an open panel.

Comment: It's not my choice that the write fails silently. The "sandboxd" process rejects the write: (Jun  1 09:28:39 Mika sandboxd[1113] ([1112]): perl5.12(1112) deny file-write-create /Users/thomas/Desktop/IMG_4679.JPG_tmp) but my app does not get any feedback. It's precisely why I want to preempt the user selecting resources he can't ultimately process. I can't really use the entitlement you suggested since I actually create a temporary file before I write to the user-selected file (non-destructive editing).

Comment: If the sandbox daemon denies filesystem access, whatever attempted that access is informed that the method/function it called failed. That failure should be propagated back to you as a client of the third-party utility. Anything else is a shocking design failure

Comment: And it doesn't matter that the write is attempted via a temporary file. That's exactly what Cocoa does for its "atomic" writing support. Where is this temporary file being written?

Comment: It was an overlook on my part that I wasn't catching the failure message from the 3rd-party utility. I agree with you, I will be fixing it. To answer you last question, the temp file is created in the same folder that the selected picture is in. So if the user selects a picture from 
~/Pictures"

Comment: then it's fine. If the user selects a picture from another folder that I don't have entitlements for, it fails.

Comment: Aha, so use something like NSTemporaryDirectory to give you a proper temp location you can write to, rather than alongside the target image.

Answer (score -3):

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:path]
```